# функция сравнивающая элементы массива на JS

Tags: javascript

```js
let arrf = (arr1, arr2) => {
    if (arr1.lenght != arr2.lenght) return 0;
    else {
        for (let i = 0; i < arr1.lenght; i++) {
            if (arr1[i] != arr2[i]) return 0;
            else if (i = arr1[arr1.lenght - 1] && arr1[i] === arr2[i]) return 1;
        }
    }    
};
```

Функция постоянно выдаёт undefined, понятия не имею почему.

Comment: А почему такие трюки, если можно просто: `arr1.every((item, index) => item == arr2[index])`?

Comment: ну очевидно что код не попадает ни в одну ветку if

Comment: Привели бы входные данные для понимая, а так, скорее всего вы не попадаете в ваши if, особенно последний `if (i = arr1[arr1.lenght - 1] && arr1[i] === arr2[i])`. А по коду, если вы сюда не попали, то ничего не возвращаете.

Comment: @eccs0103 спасибо, я не знал о .every только месяц как учу джаваскрипт

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну это я и так понял только не понял почему

Comment: 1)Не ``lenght``, а ``length``. 2) ``else`` и ``else if`` не нужны. То, что в ``else if `` лучше вынести из цикла.

Comment: @Cacat ну что то в условии не так.. воспользуйся отладкой, чтобы понять что именно

Comment: Я написал Вам решение в вашем вопросе)